# Traditional Auth, Facebook Connect & Grails

Tags: grails, facebook, spring-security, jsecurity

I am writing an app which needs to have both the traditional form of user auth, and Facebook Connect. I am using groovy/grails for this application.

Grails luckily has JSecurity plugin, Acegi Plugin and Facebook Connect. The Acegi plugin claims to have OpenId and Facebook Connect support too. Anyone's got any experience getting it to work?

Should I go with Acegi (with its Facebook Connect support), or modify Jsecurity to integrate with the Facebook Connect plugin? Which one is easy to implement? Based on my little research, I get the feeling its may not be a smooth ride that it usually is with many things in Grails.

Ideally, I would like the user to login using any or both of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have yet to try this myself, but according to this doc, it's pretty simple to use the Acegi Plugin with Facebook Connect:

http://www.grails.org/AcegiSecurity+Plugin+-+Facebook+Connect+Integration

Good luck!